# Call a new page and display content on successful Facebook authentication

Tags: cordova, typescript, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I have file structure like below

```
-pages
  -about
    about.html
    about.module.ts
    about.scss
    about.ts
  -home
    home.html
    home.scss
    home.ts
```

I have a login button and its click function inside home.html and this function is inside home.ts file

```
export class HomePage {
    userProfile: any = null;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private facebook: Facebook) {
        this.navCtrl = navCtrl;
        this.facebook = facebook;
    }
    onLoadAboutUs(): void {
        // this.navCtrl.push(AboutPage);
        this.facebook.login(['email']).then( (response) => {
            const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider
            .credential(response.authResponse.accessToken);

            firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)
            .then((success) => {
                console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(success));
                this.userProfile = success;
                this.navCtrl.push(AboutPage, {
                    userProfile: this.userProfile
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Firebase failure: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        });
    }

}
```

Now once the user is authenticate, I want to show the profile in about.html page. I have following lines in about.html page

```
<ion-content padding>
    <p>This is About Us Page.</p>
    <ion-card *ngIf="userProfile">
        <img [src]="userProfile.photoURL"/>
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title>
                {{ userProfile.displayName }}
            </ion-card-title>
            <p>
                The UID for this new user is {{userProfile.uid}} and the email is {{userProfile.email}}
            </p>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

Inside about.ts

```
public userProfile;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
        this.userProfile = navParams.get("userProfile");
    }
```

But nothing are being displayed. I am not sure where I did mistake.

Comment: Please make a `console.log(this.userProfile)` after you get it in constructor and show what is the result.

Comment: @Duannx Thank you. I found out the problem. The issue was with JSON.parse